# Java read stream on SerialPort from Arduino Nano on Linux

Tags: java, linux, arduino

Arduino nano is set to send me "test" on serial port with baud rate 9600. Using fazecast jSerialComm library I wrote a test app to display the sent data on my computer. I want to write to arduino and read from arduino at some point. I'm fairly new with this serial communication.
This is my Java code:

```
public class main {

    private static int baudRate = 9600;
    private static int dataBits = 8;
    private static int stopBits = 1;
    private static int parity = 0;
    private static int readTimeout = 0;
    private static int writeTimeout = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        SerialPort sp = SerialPort.getCommPort("/dev/ttyUSB0"); 
        sp.setComPortParameters(baudRate, dataBits, stopBits, parity);
        sp.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_WRITE_BLOCKING, readTimeout, writeTimeout); 

        if (sp.openPort()) {
            System.out.println("Port is open");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to open port");
            return;
        }

        for (Integer i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            sp.getOutputStream().write(i.byteValue());
            sp.getOutputStream().flush();
            System.out.println("Sent number: " + i);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        if(sp.getInputStream() != null){
            System.out.print(sp.getInputStream().read());
        }

        if (sp.closePort()) {
            System.out.println("Port is closed :)");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to close port :(");
            return;
        }

    }

}
```

I for some reason can't open port. It always says "Failed to open port". I did `ls /dev/tty*` in terminal and then unplugged Arduino nano and the only `/dev/ttyUSB0` gets removed. When I plug it back in and run the command the same one reappears. I thought that maybe that was the problem, but probably not. What am I doing wrong? I think I read something a while back about being it a linux problem but I can't seem to find it; could this be linux related problem?

Answer (score 1):

It was indeed a linux problem. It has something to do with permissions to ports. I had to do `sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0` to fix that. But I'll need to do that each boot so I'm kind of still looking for a long term solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by creating this file: `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-arduino_ch340.rules`

And its content is:

```
#Arduino CH340 IDs

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="usb_device", ATTR{idVendor}=="1a86", ATTR{idProduct}=="7523", GROUP="users", MODE="0777"
```

I'm using a clone with CH340G chip. You might need to alter the IDs (just use lsusb to get IDs).

Adding your user to the dialout group might be good as well. (I can't test it right now)